# How to get value from Map by one field of key?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a map:

```
public class MyKey {
    ...
    private long id;
    ...
}

Map<MyKey, String> myMap;
```

How to get value from `myMap` by `MyKey.id` field?

Comment: You'll either have to iterate over all the entries to find a match or build a new Map where the key is MyKey.id

Comment: In `O(1)`, you cannot. Unless your `MyKey` implements `equals` and `hashCode` based on `MyKey.id`; in which case you can just call `get` with a `MyKey` with the appropriate `id`.

Comment: You must override `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: What do you think, can I do like that: `myMap.get(new MyKey(someId));` ? Or it is a bad solution?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the reply in C#. I think we can achieve the same using a Linq expression. Please find the sample code below hope it will help.

```
    public class MyKey
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<MyKey, String> myMap = new Dictionary<MyKey, string>();
        myMap.Add(new MyKey() { ID = 100 }, "One");
        myMap.Add(new MyKey() { ID = 200 }, "Two");
        myMap.Add(new MyKey() { ID = 300 }, "Three");

        long searchKey = 200;
        string value = myMap[myMap.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == searchKey)];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, in java8 it looks like this: `Map<Language, String> myMap;
            Optional<MyKey> myKeyOptional = myMap.keySet().stream().filter(myKey-> myKey.getId() == someId).findFirst();

            if (myKeyOptional.isPresent()) {
                name = myMap.get(myKeyOptional.get());
            }`

Comment: Ok happy to know its helped you... Thanks